# how to make that only certain class can access a class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, permissions

What I want to do is forbidding SomeRandom class accessing Protected class

```
public class CertainClass {
    public void CerFunc(){
        ProtectedClass.ProtectedFunction();
    }
}
public class ProtectedClass {
    public static void ProtectedFunction(){
        Debug.Log("Protected");
    }
}
public class SomeRandomClass {
    public void RandFunc(){
        ProtectedClass.ProtectedFunction(); // innaccessible due to protection level
    }
}
```

what do I have to change in order to make that work?

Preferably Static, because I need and want it only 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it **private nested class** of CertainClass:

```
public class CertainClass
{
    private class ProtectedClass
    {
        public static void ProtectedFunction()
        {
            Debug.Log("Protected");
        }
    }
    public void CerFunc()
    {
        ProtectedClass.ProtectedFunction();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want another `CertainClass2` to access your `ProtectedClass` members -

Either make `CertainClass2` as public nested class of `CertainClass`.

OR

I would suggest to move `ProtectedClass` and other classes which want to access it into another **assembly** and make `ProtectedClass` as `internal` so that all classes in that assembly can have access to this class and it is invisible to other classes outside this assembly.

Comment: thanks, also how do I make it 2 CertainClasses can acces it but not other Randomclasses?

Comment: Please see the update in answer for your above comment.