# C# Restrict which classes can call a method

Tags: c#

I want to be able to restrict which classes have access to call a method of another class.  I have a the following:

```
public class A: B
{
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        C.Method1(); // should compile
    }
}

public abstract class B
{

}

public class D
{
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        C.Method1(); // shouldn't compile
    }
}

public static class C
{
    public static void Method1()
    {

    }

    public static void Method2()
    {
       ...
       Method1();
       ...
    }

}
```

All of these classes are in the same assembly, but class B is in a different assembly.

My goal is for class A to be able to call C.Method1, but have class D not able to call C.Method1

I was thinking of making class C a parent class, and have class A inherit class B, but class A already inherits from class B.

Method1 doesn't belong in class A or B.

A practical use for this is when Method1 is a utility method, and should only be called by class A and class C

Comment: How about moving Method1 to class A?

Comment: You can only apply an [access modifier restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) by assembly (e.g. `internal`) or inheritance (e.g. `protected`). There is no "friend" annotation in C#.

Comment: I like your question but I wonder why you want this. Just to know if it is a nice question or has practical use.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/21651101/3246555

Comment: updated the original post to answer your question, patrick

Comment: @user2864740 while there is no friend keyword, you can achieve similar (at least at the assembly level) via the [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo()] attribute. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx

Comment: If Method1 is really a utility method, why do you have to control who calls it?  What is gained or what do you prevent by controlling this?  Can you give any more detail so we can understand this requirement?

Answer (score 3):

Without moving methods around, you'd have to make `C` non-`static`, make `Method1` `protected`, then have `B` inherit from `C`, which would look like:

```
public class A : B
{
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        C.Method1(); // should compile
    }
}

public abstract class B : C
{
}

public class D
{
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        C.Method1(); // shouldn't compile
    }
}

public class C
{
    protected static void Method1()
    {
    }
}
```